# Where to persistently store basic component-specific state

Tags: react-native, react-redux, electron

I'm very new to React + Electron. I'm wondering where most people store basic, component-specific state.

Scenario: I have created a custom component. Basically a type of table. The relevant bit of this table to the question is that I allow users to show/hide columns, or even modify the column order.

- I'd like these 'column settings' to persist even if the user closes and reopens the application.
- No other part of the application is interested in the column settings. They simply affect what is shown in the custom table component.
- The underlying data model is not affected by these settings.

I've looked around at a bunch of solutions. Most will probably work, but not sure which is *appropriate*.

**Redux**: I could store these bits of component state there. However, the Redux docs give the impression that it is more targeted towards storing global app state. No other component in my application cares which columns the user chose to hide in this table. Thus, it would seem like a gratuitous use of Redux, when this probably should be something handled locally in the component irrespective of whether Redux is present or not.

**Localstorage**: This would probably work. Main concern is if the user decides to run multiple instances of the app. There could be a vanishingly rare race condition if both instances decide to save the column state at the same time. I don't consider restricting app instancing a proportionate solution just for something as trivial as these columns settings.

**electron-store**: Says it does atomic writes. But what if I want to use this component one day outside of electron (say in a web app *nb: this is very low priority consideration - i'm very unlikely to use it outside of electron*)? Should I tie the component to electron just for this? Also, is using ipc (since e-s lives in the main proc) to save trivial settings like this overkill?

What do people do for this?

Comment: Are you going to allow user to load table settings across different devices? Are we talking about session settings or persisting user settings (connected to user account not device)?

Comment: No. It is much simpler than any of that. This setting will only be persisted at the the app level. If that same end-user installs that app elsewhere, the column settings will not be shared.
Basically, if someone installs the app, reorganises the columns, I'd like it to remember the change next time *anyone* starts the app on *that machine*. That's all.

Comment: How would you have a situation in which you save column order in the same time over 2 instances of your app? For me, good approach is to use localStorage. It's easy, fast & you tie that setting to the specific machine, which is what you planned to do originally.

Comment: Well the user could open the app, then open another instance. What happens if the localstorage save happens at the same time? My understanding is that localstorage isn't protected vs race conditions (maybe i'm wrong?). Extremely rare possibility, but usually indicates that is the wrong solution does it not?

Comment: The worst thing that could happen is to override previous setting, which in this particular case is not something I would personally consider as dangerous. Unless you're creating a bulletproof app which should protect user from such case, you're good to go with this approach :) As an example... I saw that Visual Studio Code is applying changes to each instance regarding sidebar setting (2 instances get the same sidebar look). But if you have a plugin which could be adjusted per project (like a formatter), in that case you need an additional space/file to store settings for that project.

Comment: Thanks. Overriding previous is fine. I was more worried that if the writes occurred near simultaneously, the localstorage data could be corrupted (ie: contents of the second write being dumped in the middle of the contents of the first). Only way to avoid that is to ensure atomic writes.